# Flutter Operation was rejected while querying the subchild of doc in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an eCommerce app and working on a coupon system while creating a query I'm getting this error every time.

`FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.)`

I tried to search the error but couldn't find the exact solution as some answers suggest that I have to create a collection index which I did but still getting the same error.

[image]

This how my query looks like:-

```
Future<void> fetchCouponCode(
    String couponCode,
    String userId,
    String priductCategory,
    String productIds,
) async {
   if (couponCode == null) {
      return;
   }
   if (userId == null) {
      return;
   }
   print(couponCode);
   var today = DateTime.now();
   await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('coupons')
      .where('code', isEqualTo: couponCode)
      .where('product_categories', isEqualTo: priductCategory)
      .where('customer_email', isEqualTo: 'all')
      .where('product_ids', arrayContainsAny: [productIds])
      // .where('constraints.BagConstraints.min_item', isGreaterThan: 1)
      .where('is_enabled', isEqualTo: true)
      .where('valid_from',
        isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: today)
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
          print('=========object=======');
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
              print(element.get('discount'));
          });
          
       });
  }
```

This is how my coupon structure looks like

```
   var uuid = Uuid();
  {
    'coupon_id': uuid.v4(),
    'code': 'V710OFF',
    'description': 'Summer Sale',
    'discount': 40,
    'minimum_dicount': 30,
    'maximum_discount': 150,
    'discount_type': 'percent',
    'product_ids': ['3'],
    'date_created': DateTime.now(),
    'exclude_product_ids': 2,
    'product_categories': 't-shirts',
    'exclude_product_categories': '',
    'customer_email': 'all',
    'constraints': {
      'commonConstraints': {
        'uniqueId': uuid.v4(),
        'device_type': 'ios',
        'valid_from': DateTime.now(),
        'valid_until': DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 10)),
        'usage_limit': 1,
        'usage_limit_per_user': 1,
        'total_usage': 10
      },
      'BagConstraints': {
        'uniqueId': uuid.v4(),
        'min_value': 120,
        'max_value': 3000,
        'min_item': 1,
        'max_item': 4,
      }
    },
    'is_enabled': true
  }
```

[image]

I need to check if the coupon is invalid date range. So shall I do inside `querySnapshot.docs.forEach` as this can be done but what if I have a similar issue with another collection. How do I query third-level docs or this can't be achieved right now?? Also I go through firestore documentation and youtube channel but couldn't find the solution

And this is how I query coupon

```
fetchCouponCode(
    'V710OFF', currentFirebaseUser.uid, 't-shirts', '3');
```

Answer (score 1):

The index you've created won't work for the query you are trying to perform. Try creating this index:

[image]

| Collection ID | Field Indexed | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| coupons | product_ids | Arrays |
|  | code | Ascending |
|  | customer_email | Ascending |
|  | is_enabled | Ascending |
|  | prodcut_categories | Ascending |
|  | valid_from | Ascending |

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj I don't have a problem querying for these  `product_ids` `code` `customer_email` `is_enabled` `prodcut_categories` only problem I'm facing with valid_from so still I have to create for the above list?

Comment: @Niraj I you would have to create the index as shown above. That index is also created by the link thrown in error by Admin SDK. The query worked perfectly for me with above index.

Comment: I did the same now still getting the same issue, valid from is third level I think that might be issue